# Pagination in wordpress posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been given this post template to work with, I am trying to get the posts to paginate, how would I go about achieving this? Apologies if I am asking about this/approaching this in a naive way.

I've tried following the WordPress guides but they don't seem to match up with what I've got and I'm struggling to extrapolate.

Hope this all makes sense, many thanks.

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5' ); ?>
<?php $postLoops = 0 ?>

<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
<?php $postLoops++;
if ($postLoops == 2) {
    echo '<div class="post-right-half">';
}
if ($postLoops == 1) {
    echo '<div class="post-left-half">';
}

?>
<div class="post-square">
    <div class="post-thumbnail" style="background-image: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>);"><br></div>
    <div class="content-half">
        <h2 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <p class="post-content"><?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?</p>
        <a class="read-more" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Read More <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
if ($postLoops == 3) {
    echo '</div>';
}
if ($postLoops == 1) {
    echo '</div>';
}
?>

<?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display pagination links with `the_posts_pagination()`.

It's a template tag so it displays the pagination (no need to `echo` the result).

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_posts_pagination

If you prefer to get the mark up first and process it before you echo it, then `get_the_posts_pagination()` is your friend.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_posts_pagination

Answer (score 0):

So I dont know how universal this is, but from a combination of the commented doc links and some further research this is the solution I arrived at:

The top two lines became this:

```
<?php $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1; ?>
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => 12,'paged' => $paged) ); ?>
<?php $postLoops = 0 ?>
```

It's a bit complicated but I think the core of it is that I had to turn the query settings into an array, which includes the paged variable which is defined above (not sure I totally understand that bit yet but I'm working on it).

Then at the bottom of my page where I want my links to appear, I put in this crazy array that we modified to suit what we needed it to do, which looks complicated but essentially just includes all the settings you might need, including setting the previous and next buttons as font awesome buttons:

```
<?php 
    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
        'total'        => $the_query->max_num_pages,
        'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
        'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
        'show_all'     => false,
        'type'         => 'plain',
        'end_size'     => 2,
        'mid_size'     => 1,
        'prev_next'    => true,
        'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( '<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>', 'text-domain' ) ),
        'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( '<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>', 'text-domain' ) ),
        'add_args'     => false,
        'add_fragment' => '',
    ) );
?>
```

I think that's everything, I'll add more description if I understand it a bit more but it seems to work for now.

Many thanks.